# How to check a checkbox in PDF file with the same variable name with iText and Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have been using `iText` library for `Java` to fill automatically a PDF Document. The first thing I do is map every field. Once I get every field mapped, I save the variables name into `Strings` to be easy to be accessible.

So far, so good. The problem is that I have a group of 6 checkboxes with the same variable name. For exemple, they are named `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`.

With some tests I could figure out that if I check the first checkbox so the `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0] = 1`

If I check the second one (that unchecks the first automatically) so `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0] = 2`

Then `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0] = 3` successively until it gets the the number `6` that is the last one.

I am using `form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]", "1");`to fill up the fields. When I fill with the value `1` the first checkbox gets checked, but when I fill with the number `2` that should check the second checkbox it does not work. It does not matter if I choose `2, 3, 4, 5 or 6` it just does not work, the checkboxes stay empty and I can`t check them.

Here a piece of the code:

```
String _5_1 = "topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]";

AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

form.setField(_5_1, "3");
```

Please, I need suggestions.

Comment: As @Bruno said, please share the PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to quote from ISO-32000-1 section 12.7.3.2 "Field names":

> It is possible for different field dictionaries to have the same fully
>   qualified field name if they are descendants of a common ancestor with
>   that name and have no partial field names (T entries) of their own.
>   Such field dictionaries are different representations of the same
>   underlying field; they should differ only in properties that specify
>   their visual appearance. In particular, field dictionaries with the
>   same fully qualified field name shall have the same field type (FT),
>   value (V), and default value (DV).

If we apply this to your question: it is possible for different field dictionaries to have the same name `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`. Such field dictionaries are different representations of **the same field** and they shall have the same value.

There are two options:

1. If you have a PDF with field dictionaries with name (`topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`) that have different values, then you don't have a valid PDF file: it is in violation with ISO-32000-1, which is the official PDF specification.
2. Maybe you think that you have check boxes with the same field name and different values, but maybe those check boxes are in reality a radio field with different radio buttons. Maybe you are not using the correct values. Maybe something else is at play. For a SO reader to be able to help you, he'd need to see the PDF file.

If option 1 applies, abandon all hope: you have a bad PDF. Fix it or throw it away. If option 2 applies, please share the PDF.

**Update after inspecting the PDF file:**

Option 2 applies. You have a hybrid form, which means that the form is described twice inside the PDF, once using AcroForm technology and once using XFA. Please start by reading my answer to the following question: [PDFTK and removing the XFA format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633873/pdftk-and-removing-the-xfa-format)

When you open the PDF in Adobe Reader, you will notice that the fields act as if they are radio buttons. When you click one, it is selected, but when you click another, it is selected, but the first one is no longer selected.

What you see, is the form as described in XFA, and there are some important differences between the XFA form and the AcroForm description. This isn't an error. It's inherent to hybrid forms.

When you fill out the form using:

```
form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]", "1");
```

iText fills out the AcroForm correctly, but it fails at filling out the XFA form because iText makes an educated guess (not an accurate guess) as to where the corresponding value should be set in the XFA stream (which is actually expressed in XML). For more details: this is explained in chapter 8 of [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book).

What I usually do in such cases is exactly what the person who asked if he could safely throw away the XFA part does: I remove the XFA part:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.removeXfa();
```

This simplifies things dramatically, but it doesn't solve your problem yet. To solve your problem, we need to look inside the PDF:

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot (taken from [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups)), there are two different descriptions for the form: you have a `/Fields` array (the AcroForm description) and you have an `/XFA` part that consists of different streams that, if you join them, form a large XML file.

We also see that where you think there's a single field `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`, there are in reality 6 fields:

```
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[1]
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[2]
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[3]
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[4]
topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[5]
```

Now let's take a look inside those fields.

This is field `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`:

[image]

This is field `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]`:

[image]

These are AcroForm check boxes, but there an instruction meant for humans that says: select only one. This instruction can be understood by humans only, not by machines or software.

My first attempt at writing the [FillHybridForm](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FillHybridForm) example failed because I made a similar error to yours. I didn't look closely enough at the different appearance states. I thought that the **On** value of `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]` was `0`, of `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[1]` was `1`, and so on. It wasn't... The **On** value of `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]` was `1`, of `topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[1]` was `2`, and so on.

This is how you can fill out all the check boxes:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.removeXfa();
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[0]", "1");
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[1]", "2");
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[2]", "3");
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[3]", "4");
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[4]", "5");
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].p2_cb01[5]", "6");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Now all the check boxes are checked. See [f8966_filled.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/f8966_filled.pdf):

[image]

Of course: being human, we know that we shouldn't do this, because we should treat the fields as if they were radio buttons, but there is no *technical reason* in the AcroForm description why we couldn't. The logic that prevents us to do so, is only present in the XFA description.

This solves your problem if it is acceptable to throw away the XFA part. It will also solve your problem if it's OK to flatten the form in which case you should add:

```
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

If you the above options aren't acceptable, you shouldn't throw away the XFA part, but fill out the AcroForm part as described above *and* use iText to extract the XML dataset (see `datasets` in the first screen shot), update it the way the US government expect you to update it, and use iText to put the updates dataset back in the `datasets` object.

Phew... This is one of the longest answers I ever wrote on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hello, I think the PDF was broken, I am downloading a new one that seems to be fixed, I will share the results here as soon I am done. Thank you!

Edit: Ok, I got another PDF file here and it is still not working. The PDF file is hosted here:

http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-access/f8966_accessible.pdf

It`s from US Government, so, probably it's not broken.

Comment: It's a hybrid XFA form. This means that you have both an AcroForm and an XFA form inside. That always complicates things. But at first sight, it looks as if you made a mistake. I'll see if I can create a code sample to show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Ok, everything is working fine BUT the "Part V Number 1"

Try to check only 1 box at this specific part, that is the only "broken" part. Thank you

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much for your answerer. You did not just solved my problem, you made me understand perfectly what is happening with this PDF. Thank you very much again!