# Problems scanning the 1042-S 2015 PDF file with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am building a program that will write automatically into a PDF file. I am using the library `iText` to do.

Well, to check the name of the fields I run this small code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDF_PATH);

    AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();

    Set<String> fldNames = fields.getFields().keySet(); 


    for (String fldName : fldNames) {
      System.out.println( fldName + ": " + fields.getField(fldName));
    }
}
```

The output is something like:

> topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group12-13[0].Line13d-g[0].Line13e[0]: 13e
>   topmostSubform[0].CopyB[0].Group1-11[0].Line3[0].Line3[0]: 0
>   topmostSubform[0].CopyE[0].Group1-11[0].Line7[0]: 7
>   topmostSubform[0].CopyD[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0].Line15i[0]: 15i

the `topmostSubform[0].CopyE[0].Group1-11[0].Line7[0]` is the value that I am looking for and what comes after the `:` is the value that I put in the original PDF to keep track of the variable names of each field.

So far so good, but I am having problem with 1 specific field. The field number `16`. I input the value `16` to keep track but in my output there is only 1 `16` output but It was supposed to have 5 Copies, the `CopyA` , `CopyB`, `CopyC`, `CopyD` and `CopyE`. What I find is only this:

`topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0]` and when I try to write in this field using this code:

`form.setField("topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0]", "BLA BLA BLA");` it does not work. Obviously something weird is happening with the `16` Field.

The PDF can be Downloaded at: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1042s--2015.pdf

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is a *hybrid XFA form* (or, as I like to call such forms, an abomination). In a *hybrid XFA form*, the fields of the form are described twice, once using PDF syntax (pure AcroForm technology), once using XML (the XML Forms Architecture, aka XFA).

This is problematic because:

- There are differences between the form functionality in AcroForm functionality versus the XML Forms Architecture.
- There's always the risk that the form described in PDF syntax doesn't correspond with the form in XML syntax.

That's why I always throw away the XML syntax. See the [FillHybridForm](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/filling-out-forms#1164-fillhybridform.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.removeXfa();
    form.setField("topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0]", "16");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

This line is the one you probably don't have in your code:

```
form.removeXfa();
```

Please read my answers to the following questions for more info:

- [How to check a checkbox in PDF file with the same variable name with iText and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702986)
- [How to change the text color of an AcroForm field?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-change-text-color-acroform-field)
- [Is it safe to remove XFA?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/it-safe-remove-xfa)

If you only have time to read one Q&A from the list above, choose the last one in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood the solution, even that one of the questions that you listed is a question that I made. Even If I add the `form.removeXfa()` it still does not work, maybe I need to set something else? When I add the `form.removeXfa()` all the remaining fields stop working, I can't put any values on the remaining fields (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23)

Comment: Sorry or my previous answer, I will try to explain what really happened. Even when I add the line `form.removeXfa();` the number 16 does not get written using the code `form.setField("topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0]", "16");` Problably it's because the name   `topmostSubform[0].CopyA[0].Group14-24[0].Line16[0]` is not the right name for this Field. That happened in this topic: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/it-safe-remove-xfa Any advise in how to get the real variable name for the Field 16?

Comment: Ok, I got this, I used the Tool PDF RUP (http://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/itext-rups-use-rups-change-your-pdf-syntax-and-dictionaries) and I saw that the Field 16 changes the name. Thanks for the answer